# History of anyon theory, braidings and tensor categories

Tags: mathematics, topological-quantum-computing, anyons, history

What was the first paper/who was the first person to phrase anyon theory in terms of tensor categories?

Going through Wilczek's book on fractional statistics, some of the reprinted papers anticipate such a formulation, but I am looking for the historically first paper(s) which seriously uses tensor category language.

Is it Kitaev?

Comment: Given that Reshetikhin-Turaev was early 90s, I would look around that time period. But you may not see the word anyon if people were still groaning at using such a pun as a name.